# AWK - Print complete input string after comparison

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file a.text:

```
hello world
my world
hello universe
```

I want to print the complete string if the second word is "world":

```
[root@sc-rdops-vm18-dhcp-57-128:/var/log] cat a | awk -F " " '{if($2=="world") print $1}'
hello
my
```

But the output which I want is:

```
[root@sc-rdops-vm18-dhcp-57-128:/var/log] cat a | awk -F " " '{if($2=="world") print <Something here>}'
hello world
my world
```

Any pointers on how I can do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I only want to print the complete input line when the 2nd element is "world".

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '{if ($2=="world") {print}}' file
```

Output:

```
hello world
my world
```

Answer (score 2):

First off, since you are writing a single if statement, you can use the `awk 'filter{commands;}'` pattern, like so

```
awk -F " " '$2=="world" { print <Something here> }'
```

To print the entire line you can use `print $0`

```
awk -F " " '$2=="world"{print $0}' file
```

which can be written as

```
awk -F " " '$2=="world"{print}' file
```

But `{print}` is the default action, so it can be omitted after the filter like this:

```
awk -F " " '$2=="world"' file
```

Or even without the -F option, since the space is the default FS value

```
awk '$2=="world"' file
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want / have to use `awk` to solve your problem:

```
 awk '$0~/world/' file.txt
```

If a line (i.e., `$0`) matches the string "world" (i.e., `~/world/`) the entire line is printed

If you only want to check the second column for `world`:

```
 awk '$2 == "world"' file.txt
```

Comment: You don't need the `$0~` in `$0~/world/`, just `/world/` would suffice.

Comment: @EdMorton Thank you for the hint! I couldn't imagine there was an even shorter solution